# Restoring from a snapshot in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, datastax

As per Cassandra document,
When taking snapshot in Cassandra for a keyspace,the snapshot is created in `data_directory_location/keyspace_name/table_name-UUID/snapshots/snapshot_name directory`.
I have around 20 tables in a keyspace,in each table directory, I see the snapshot folder.

So, while restoring from snapshot, I need to copy the contents to Copy its contents into this directory:
`data_directory_location/keyspace_name/table_name-UUID directory`.

So, does it mean that I need to copy the snapshot contents from each of the table's directory and paste it to the corresponding table directory?

What is the correct and efficient procedure for this?